# Not able to use 7-Zip to compress stdin and output with stdout?

Tags: c#, stdout, stdin, 7zip

I get the error "Not implemented".

I want to compress a file using [7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip) via stdin then take the data via stdout and do more conversions with my application. In the [man page](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/7z) it shows this example:

[% echo foo | 7z a dummy -tgzip -si -so > /dev/null](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/commandes/7z)

I am using Windows and C#.

Results:

```
7-Zip 4.65  Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Igor Pavlov  2009-02-03
Creating archive StdOut

System error:
Not implemented
```

Code:

```
public static byte[] a7zipBuf(byte[] b)
{
    string line;
    var p = new Process();
    line = string.Format("a dummy -t7z -si -so ");
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = line;
    p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe";
    p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

    p.Start();

    p.StandardInput.BaseStream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
    p.StandardInput.Close();
    Console.Write(p.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
    //Console.Write(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

    return p.StandardOutput.BaseStream.ReadFully();
}
```

Is there another simple way to read the file into memory?

Right now I can 1) write to a temporary file and read (easy and can copy/paste some code) 2) use a file pipe (medium? I have never done it) 3) Something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to try out something like SevenZipSharp http://www.codeplex.com/sevenzipsharp, I've never used it personally but it provides a wrapper to the 7za.dll COM library which may be helpful to you.

I've written utilities that utilise 7-Zip via a process myself and haven't had issues though I've never tried to do StdIn and StdOut stuff.  In the Help files I have with my version of 7-Zip the page on the -si switch states:

> Note: The current version of 7-Zip does not support reading of archives from stdin.

Note sure if this might be the source of your problem, with specifying both switches it might be confusing 7-Zip.

The examples they show in the help seem to show that -so is used to redirect the output to standard out but requires normal file based inputs to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Here's some info from Igor Pavlov (7z's author), in a thread about ["7zip as a drop-in replacement for gzip/bzip2?"](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/f3720dde/)

The suggestion was to basically use 7z as an `xz` surrogate. Just using `xz` should work, but it may not be multi-threaded (and 7z may be).

While attempting to use 7z as in:

```
somecommand | 7zr a -si -so | nc -q 2 1.2.3.4 5678
```

[Igor Pavlov says](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/f3720dde/#85d3):

> 7z a a.7z -so
>   and
>   7z e a.7z -si
>   can not be implemeted. since .7z format requires
>   "Seek" operation.
>
> Use xz format instead:
>   7z a a.xz file
>   it must support all modes.

[And](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/f3720dde/#56b6)

> 7-Zip thinks that it needs archive name.
>   So you can specify some
>   archive name like a.xz
>   or
>   specify -an switch.

The eventual solution was:

```
cat foo.txt | 7za a -an -txz -bd -si -so | dd of=foo.xz
```

---

[A bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/bugs/1312/) suggests this should be in the help:

> The current version of 7-Zip support reading of archives from stdin only for xz, lzma, tar, gzip and bzip2 archives, and adding files from stdin only for 7z, xz, gzip and bzip2 archives.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use `7za.exe`, which is the "Commandline version" on the [7z download page](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html).  I see that you are currently using `7z.exe`, and I'm pretty sure that's a problem I've encountered before as well.

---

Actually, I think I switched to [PeaZip](http://peazip.sourceforge.net) because of the troubles 7z was giving me.  PeaZip is a wrapper around 7z and a few other compression utilities, and PeaZip has a little bit better command line interface.

Comment: @ Mark: 7za is the reduced version of 7z (drops the support for some archive types), 7z is the command line version of 7-Zip (supports the same archive types).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem when piping `stdout` into `7zip`

Instead of invoking the command from `Process` directly, I write the command to a batch file and then run the batch file.  It's a hack, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use `xz`, which by default uses the same compression algorithm as 7-zip, with the `-T0` param, which makes `xz` multithreaded scaling to the number of your CPU cores automatically, and as fast as 7-zip.

`some_command | xz -T0 > some_file.xz`