# Create Postgres password protected backup from C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, 7zip

I want to create a password protected Postgres backup from C#

I tried next code but I think there is a more secure way: to pass backup directly from pg_dump to arhive without saving it on the disk and to add password form env variable like is done with PGPASSWORD

```
   string pgDumpPath, outFile, host, port, database, user, password, dumpCommand, batFilePath, zipPth, outPath, tmpPath;

    pgDumpPath = @"d:\_dev_\postgres\pgsql\bin\pg_dump.exe";
    host = "127.0.0.1";
    port = "5432";
    database = "postgres";
    user = "postgres";
    password = "mypass";
    dumpCommand = pgDumpPath + " -Fc" + " -h " + host + " -p " + port + " -d " + database + " -U " + user;
    tmpPath = Path.GetTempPath();
    batFilePath = tmpPath + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".cmd";

    outFile = @"myBackup";

    outPath = @"d:\";

    zipPth = @"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe";
    string tmpfile = "\"" + tmpPath + outFile + ".sql\"";
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PGPASSWORD", password);

    try
    {


        File.WriteAllText(batFilePath,
         "@echo off " + "\n" +
          dumpCommand + "  > " + tmpfile + "\n" + "\"" +
          zipPth + "\"" + " a \"" + outPath + outFile + ".zip\" -p" + password + " " +tmpfile +
           "  &DEL " + tmpfile  +
           "  &DEL \"" + batFilePath + "\"",
         Encoding.ASCII);


        if (File.Exists(tmpfile))
            File.Delete(tmpfile);

        var oInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(batFilePath)
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };

        using (var proc = Process.Start(oInfo))
        {
            proc.WaitForExit();
            proc.Close();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (File.Exists(batFilePath))
            File.Delete(batFilePath);

    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a ZIP archive in memory using System.IO.Compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232414/creating-a-zip-archive-in-memory-using-system-io-compression)

Comment: no,the question is not how to create a zip in .net si how to directly pass backup file from  pg_dump to 7z/secure achive

Comment: You'll want to open the pgdump process using `new Process()`, with output redirection enabled, read the dump content into a buffer, then write the buffer to your compressed form. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29753402/51685

Comment: The question very much is how to create a 7z archive. Dumps aren't backups, they're database scripts. What you ask is how to create a password-protected ZIP or 7z package containing that dump. You want the contents of that dump to come from `pd_dump`'s standard output.

Comment: As [this related if not duplicate question shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287383/not-able-to-use-7-zip-to-compress-stdin-and-output-with-stdout) the 7z format itself can't work with `stdin` input because it requires seek access to the input. Different formats can be used with the same tool though.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `pg_dump` can do either script or a proper backup archive. See the docs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html

Comment: Using the `-Fc` option with `pg_dump` will create an archive, which is compressed by default. Compressing it again using 7z is a waste of time as there will be almost no space savings.

Comment: @Charlieface the docs say `or other archive file`. The equivalent to a SQL Server backup is called a physical backup, done using `pg_basebackup`. The OP's question is how to password-protect the backup, not so much how to compress it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got a working solution:

```
string database = "postgres",user = "postgres", password = "mypass", archivePassword = "mypass2";

            var outFile = @"d:\postgres_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy") + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM") + "_" +
                                     DateTime.Now.ToString("dd") + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh") + DateTime.Now.ToString("mm") +
                                     DateTime.Now.ToString("ss");

            var sInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = @"d:\_dev_\postgres\pgsql\bin\pg_dump.exe",
                Arguments = $"-U {user} -w {database}",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            sInfo.EnvironmentVariables.Add("PGPASSWORD", password);


            var cInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {

                FileName = @"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe",
                Arguments = $"a -p{archivePassword} -si{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(outFile)} {outFile}",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };



            using (var proc = Process.Start(sInfo))
            {
                using (var comp = Process.Start(cInfo))
                {
                    proc.StandardOutput.BaseStream.CopyTo(comp.StandardInput.BaseStream);

                    proc.WaitForExit();
                    comp.StandardInput.BaseStream.Flush();
                    comp.StandardInput.BaseStream.Dispose();
                    comp.WaitForExit();

                }
            }
```